# Regex to extract one or two values from text

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I am trying to build a regex (in python) to extract one or two values from text documents.  The pattern to match will always be of the form:

```
<div>SCORE: x to y<\/div>
```

where x and y can be between -7 and + 6.  Sometimes only one number will be present.  If there are two numbers I need to capture both. Also the 'to' maybe missing a comma or a dash or even 'too'! White space is variable.  So I need something like,

```
x,y=re.findall('<div>SCORE: (-+?[0-5])[a-zA-Z]?(-+?[0-5]?)<\/div>', text)
```

except that this is clearly not correct.  Any guidance appreciated.

Examples include

```
<div>SCORE: 0</div>
<div>SCORE: 0 to 5</div>
<div>SCORE: -1 to 6</div>
<div>SCORE: -1 to -3</div>
<div>SCORE: -4</div>
<div>SCORE: 3</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> where x and y can be between `-7` and `+6`. Sometimes only one number will be present. If there are two numbers I need to capture both. Also the `to` maybe missing a comma or a dash or even `too`! White space is variable.

You may try this regex:

```sh
<div>SCORE:\s*([+-]?[1-6]|-7|0)(?:\s*(?:[-,]|too?)\s*([+-]?[1-6]|-7|0))?</div>
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/f2kWJX/1)

**RexEx Explanation:**

- `<div>SCORE:`: Match `<div>SCORE:` text
- `\s*`: 0 or more whitespaces
- `([+-]?[1-6]|-7|0)`: Match first number between `-7` and `+6` and capture in group #1
- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `\s*`: 0 or more whitespaces
  - `(?:[-,]|too?)`: Match `-` or `,` or `to`
  - `\s*`: 0 or more whitespaces
  - `([+-]?[1-6]|-7|0)`: Match first number between `-7` and `+6` and capture in group #2
- )?`: End *optional* non-capture group #1
- `</div>`: Match closing `</div>`

Comment: Thank you - I really appreciated the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

You can write a regular expression for the expected format of numbers and then another one to describe the structure of the test they are embedded into:

```py
number_regex = r'-[1-7]|0|[1-6]|\+[1-6]'  # numbers between -7 to 6
regex = r'<div>SCORE:\s*({0})\s+\w+\s+({0})\s*<\/div>'.format(number_regex)
occurrences = re.findall(regex, text)
```

Basically, you are describing the text of interest as a string between `<div>` and `</div>`, with a sequence composed of a number, a word, and another number, separated by some spaces.

If `text` is:

```py
text = (
    "<div>SCORE: 5 to 6</div>"
    "<div>SCORE: 0 to 6</div>"
    "<div>SCORE: -7 to 6</div>"
    "<div>SCORE: -7 to -2</div>"
    "<div>SCORE:0 to +2</div>"
    "<div>SCORE:hi to 1</div>"
)
```

you get:

```py
[('5', '6'), ('0', '6'), ('-7', '6'), ('-7', '-2'), ('0', '+2')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the separator between `x` and `y` would always be a single continuous group of non whitespace characters, the following pattern should work:

```regex
<div>SCORE:\s*(\S+)\s+\S+\s+(\S+)\s*<\/div>
```

We can use `re.findall` here:

```py
inp = "<div>SCORE: x to y</div>"
matches = re.findall(r'<div>SCORE:\s*(\S+)\s+\S+\s+(\S+)\s*<\/div>', inp)
print(matches)  # [('x', 'y')]
```